# boost::asio::strand && boost::lockfree::spsc_queue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

If I am running a single an `boost::asio::io_service` with a thread pool and wrapping a particular socket receive using a `boost::asio::strand` to simulate single threaded operation, does anyone know if the strand meets the requirements to safely produce to a `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` even though I will be producing from *different* threads but guaranteed to only produce one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Serialization through a strand guarantees what you are after. To extend this a little bit, if you have multiple stands (for multiple sockets for example) - then no such guarantee exists across multiple strands pushing to the same queue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.